# Eclipse Autogenerate Project Structure

Tags: java, eclipse

Does Eclipse support the concept of reusable "project structures" via scripting/configging?

For instance if I want all of my projects - upon creation - to take on the form:

```
MyProjectRoot/
    src/
    fizz/
        buzz/
    docs/
```

Is there a way to define this project structure somewhere (XML, etc.), and then link a new project to that structure?

I know I can write an ant/maven script to do this for me, but having a resource like this would save me from a lot of manual copying & pasting the same buildscript.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, I don't think this exists.

One option is to create a template project and save the dir tree off somewhere. Then when you need a new project that should follow template, you can copy the dir tree and use File -> Import.

Another option that I'd recommend is to just use Maven and have Maven dictate dir structure.  Eclipse can then import that maven project.

Comment: I'm actually learning Maven as we speak! Is there a way to define a "workspace-wide" POM that defines directory structure, and then have each project inherit/use that "global POM". That would probably be as close to what I'm looking for as possible.

Comment: @Mara: With Maven, what you'd do is create your own archetype using the [archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/). Then you'd use archetype:generate to create the directory structure complete with pom.xml

Comment: @Mara: Maven also supports [project inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) that lets you inherit settings including directories that maven plugins use to do their job.

Comment: For better or for worse, Maven imposes a directory structure on you. It is possible to override that directory structure a bit, which could live in a parent POM, but IMHO if you've decided on maven as your build tool, you should stick to their structure to the extent that you can.  Trying to use your own dir structure and have maven conform generally ends in pain :).  Starting with an archetype as Sii suggested is a good start.  Here's the recommended structure: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: @Mara: All that said, if you're going to use Maven anyway, I'd recommend to just stick to their defaults instead of going through all this bother. Extensively customising Maven's directory structure is something I'd do to "mavenise" legacy projects, not on a whim.

Comment: I guess I'll defer to those with experience. Standard project structure it is!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. ***But not easily***. You basically have to create your own plugin, which frankly I don't see the juice being worth the squeeze. Now, if you are learning/using Maven, then you already have a very good directory layout defined for you. Getting that directory structure imported into Eclipse is a one-line command in your shell. And if you decide to switch to NetBeans then you don't even have too run that shell command (native integration ftw)!

But of course, you are constrained to Maven best-practices for directory layout (good, bad or indifferent).

I'm including a link to the Eclipse Help documentation, in the case you decide to go down the custom plugin route. Good luck!

[Custom project types in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/Howtoregistertemplates.html)